# How to make the mirror and actual mesh switch places

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I am working on a model from a video from Daniel Kreuter and I made a mistake and but the head outline and eye outline on the opposite side.
i want to know how i can make the mesh and the mirror side switch places

Comment: Apply the mirror modifier. Delete the element you don't want, Add a mirror modifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Apply the mirror modifier. Delete the [vertices] you don't want. Add a mirror modifier. – cegaton 2 hours ago

Comment: 0_0 omg i am ashamed that i was dumb enough not to think of that

Answer (score 1):

You can mirror a mesh or a part of it with the interactive mirror

- set the pivot point to 3D cursor and place it correctly.
- select the geometry you want to mirror
- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> and one of the axis (<kbd>x</kbd>,<kbd>y</kbd>,<kbd>z</kbd> )
- then press <kbd>enter</kbd> to commit

Comment: sadly this does not seem to work for me T_T